# Communication from rails with endless worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, websocket, worker

I'm implementing worker for rails+sneakers that will work for a long time(days, months). It should be websocket communication with external service.

The first concern: is it correct to run the endless process via ruby+sneakers? How can I monitor that there are no memory leaks?

Second question: What is the best way to send new commands to that worker?